# pandas rolling_max with groupby

Tags: python, pandas

What I have:

```
Sym  Date    close
A   1-Jan   45
A   2-Jan   15
A   3-Jan   55
B   1-Jan   41
B   2-Jan   87
B   3-Jan   82
C   1-Jan   33
C   2-Jan   15
C   3-Jan   46
```

What I need

```
Sym  Date  close  rolling_max_2day
A   1-Jan   45    NaN
A   2-Jan   15    45
A   3-Jan   55    55
B   1-Jan   41    NaN
B   2-Jan   87    87
B   3-Jan   82    87
C   1-Jan   33    NaN
C   2-Jan   15    33
C   3-Jan   46    46
```

The dataframe `df` is with multiple index(Sym, Date)

I have tried like this:

```
df['rolling_max_2day'] = df.groupby(level=['sym']).apply(lambda x:pd.rolling_max(x['close'].values,2))
```

it does not return any errors, but it also returns all null value at column `rolling_max_2day`

However, if only this code, not append to `df`, I can get a correct series.

```
df.groupby(level=['sym']).apply(lambda x:pd.rolling_max(x['close'].values,2))
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can apply on `df.groupby('Sym')['close']` using `pd.rolling_max(x, 2)` instead

```
In [124]: df['rolling_max_2day'] = (df.groupby('Sym')['close']
                                      .apply(lambda x:pd.rolling_max(x, 2)))

In [125]: df
Out[125]:
  Sym   Date  close  rolling_max_2day
0   A  1-Jan     45               NaN
1   A  2-Jan     15                45
2   A  3-Jan     55                55
3   B  1-Jan     41               NaN
4   B  2-Jan     87                87
5   B  3-Jan     82                87
6   C  1-Jan     33               NaN
7   C  2-Jan     15                33
8   C  3-Jan     46                46
```